# TaskScheduler - executing continuations

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronizationcontext, taskscheduler

After a bit of reading about `TaskScheduler` ([good article here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/09/22/9898090.aspx)), it turns out that a `TaskScheduler` can:

1. Schedule tasks - by using `QueueTask` method, which in the example above just `Post`s task execution to selected `SynchronizationContext`
2. Schedule continuations through the lower-level scheduler associated with the currently running framework (`SynchronizationContext`).

Is 2. in any way related to `CotninueWith` method of `Task`? I obviously understand 1., but don't see how 2. is true for `TaskScheduler`. In what method of `TaskScheduler` would that happen?

Comment: Well there are `Task.ContinueWith` overloads that *take* a `TaskScheduler` so that the continuation is scheduled by that scheduler... is that what you're thinking of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Schedule continuations through the lower-level scheduler associated
>   with the currently running framework (SynchronizationContext).

I think you got it mixed a little. You can use a given `TaskScheduler` and execute a continuation on it, not the other way around. That is exactly what this snippet from the post you shared does:

```
var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(); 
var tf = Task.Factory; 

blendedImage.ContinueWith(_ => 
{ 
    pictureBox1.Image = blendedImage.Result; 
}, ui);
```

It tells the `Task.ContinueWith` to use the UI `TaskScheduler` (which was provided by calling `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`) earlier in order to invoke the continuation on a particular context, this time being the UI message loop.

If you really want to get down to the details, when you pass a `TaskScheduler` to `ContinueWith`, it ends up passing it to a class called `StandardTaskContinuation` which has the following `Run` method that ends up calling `TaskScheduler.InternalTaskQueue`:

```
internal void ScheduleAndStart(bool needsProtection)
{
    if (needsProtection)
    {
        if (!this.MarkStarted())
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.m_stateFlags |= 65536;
    }
    if (Task.s_asyncDebuggingEnabled)
    {
        Task.AddToActiveTasks(this);
    }
    if (AsyncCausalityTracer.LoggingOn && 
       (this.Options & (TaskCreationOptions)512) == TaskCreationOptions.None)
    {
        AsyncCausalityTracer.TraceOperationCreation(
            CausalityTraceLevel.Required, this.Id, "Task: " +
            ((Delegate)this.m_action).Method.Name, 0uL);
    }
    try
    {
        this.m_taskScheduler.InternalQueueTask(this);
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException exceptionObject)
    {
        this.AddException(exceptionObject);
        this.FinishThreadAbortedTask(true, false);
    }
    catch (Exception arg_93_0)
    {
        TaskSchedulerException ex = new TaskSchedulerException(arg_93_0);
        this.AddException(ex);
        this.Finish(false);
        if ((this.Options & (TaskCreationOptions)512) == TaskCreationOptions.None)
        {
            this.m_contingentProperties.m_exceptionsHolder.MarkAsHandled(false);
        }
        throw ex;
    }
}
```